# Error when rendering blog using distill package in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I am trying to follow the steps in: https://themockup.blog/posts/2020-08-01-building-a-blog-with-distill/ , but I have error message saying R code execution error.

```
Creating website directory demo-02
Creating demo-02/_site.yml
Creating demo-02/index.Rmd
Creating demo-02/about.Rmd
Creating demo-02/_posts/welcome/welcome.Rmd


processing file: welcome.Rmd
  |.....................                                         |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.........................................                     |  67%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |..............................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: welcome.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS welcome.utf8.md --to html5 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output welcome.html --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --standalone --variable toc-float=1 --highlight-style /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/distill/rmarkdown/templates/distill_article/resources/arrow.theme --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/distill/rmarkdown/templates/distill_article/resources/default.html '--metadata=link-citations:true' --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb67b40af4html --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb19a9ff3dhtml --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb5d3b4e5chtml --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb6095a9d5html --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb1c1107dhtml --include-before-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb2a217f71html --include-before-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb7d35e952html --include-before-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb5e6946b6html --include-after-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb51a18726html --include-after-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb43aff9a8html --include-after-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb562fa74fhtml --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/rmarkdown-str7cb52915fbd.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb46249ba4html 

Output created: /Users/lruolin/Desktop/r-distill/demo-02/_site/posts/welcome/index.html
Rendering blog...

Rendering: demo-02/about.Rmd
Error in output_format_filter(x, output_format) : 
  could not find function "output_format_filter"
Creating website directory demo001
Creating demo001/_site.yml
Creating demo001/index.Rmd
Creating demo001/about.Rmd
Creating demo001/_posts/welcome/welcome.Rmd


processing file: welcome.Rmd
  |.....................                                         |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.........................................                     |  67%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |..............................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: welcome.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS welcome.utf8.md --to html5 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output welcome.html --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --standalone --variable toc-float=1 --highlight-style /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/distill/rmarkdown/templates/distill_article/resources/arrow.theme --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/distill/rmarkdown/templates/distill_article/resources/default.html '--metadata=link-citations:true' --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb4d639cehtml --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb380ba659html --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cbc6d05ddhtml --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb499bf68ahtml --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb1e5703c7html --include-before-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb62b90d60html --include-before-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb631d4c42html --include-before-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb1879b3e4html --include-after-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb5e114a49html --include-after-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb41242edehtml --include-after-body /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb2e81123bhtml --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/rmarkdown-str7cb1bd3f757.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --include-in-header /var/folders/x3/p1jlvsr16295bcpmlwd5cb5w0000gp/T//RtmplvadBq/file7cb79137f06html 

Output created: /Users/lruolin/Desktop/r-distill/demo001/_site/posts/welcome/index.html
Rendering blog...

Rendering: demo001/about.Rmd
Error in output_format_filter(x, output_format) : 
  could not find function "output_format_filter"
>
```

Please advise on how to resolve. I am using distill version 1.1, RStudio
Version 1.3.1093, R 4.0.3

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I removed the packages distill, rmarkdown, and then reinstalled rmarkdown and distill. After that, I restarted R. The problem was solved after that.